# epoll_wait() succeeds but returns -1 bytes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

Below is code I created for epoll_wait on UNIX domain datagram sockets (note this is UNIX domain, not internet domain).  Each of these C programs is by a NASM program -- the C object files are linked into the NASM executable.

I have no trouble with epoll_instance_create or add_to_epoll_fd_list (which adds each of the file descriptors).  However, epoll_wait_next calls perror and returns "epoll_wait: Success", then loops through "for(i = 0; i < event_count; i++) { " as it should, but  bytes_read is -1 on the line "bytes_read = read(events[i].data.fd, read_buffer, BUF_SIZE);"

The struct epoll_event epoll_events is defined as global so it can be passed by NASM when these programs are called.

The problem may be that I don't understand how to call read() in my context as the code comes from other code samples (this is the first time I've used epoll).

```
#define BUF_SIZE 750
#define SV_SOCK_PATH "/tmp/ud_ucase"
#define epoll_maxevents 100

struct epoll_event epoll_events;

int64_t epoll_instance_create() {
    int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
    return (int64_t) epoll_fd;
}

int64_t add_to_epoll_fd_list(int epoll_fd, int this_fd) {
    epoll_events.data.fd = epoll_fd;
    epoll_events.events = EPOLLIN;
    int res = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, this_fd,   &epoll_events);
    perror("epoll_ctl");

    if (res > 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int64_t epoll_wait_next(int epoll_fd, struct epoll_event * events){

    int event_count, i;
    ssize_t count;
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    int64_t read_buffer[750];
    int64_t test_data;

    event_count = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, epoll_maxevents, -   1);
    perror("epoll_wait");

    for(i = 0; i < event_count; i++) {

    printf("Reading file descriptor '%d' -- ", events[i].data.fd);

    bytes_read = read(events[i].data.fd, read_buffer, BUF_SIZE);

    if (bytes_read > 0)
        test_data = read_buffer[0];

    printf("%zd bytes read.\n", bytes_read);
    read_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The overall code (including the NASM code) is very large, and even a minimal version would be over 300 lines, so I have posted the relevant C programs above, which I think should be enough to spot the problem(s).

Thanks in advance for any help on understanding why bytes_read comes as -1; it should be 720 bytes.

Comment: Your `perror` isn't guarded by `if (event_count != -1)` ...

Comment: Do you think that's why I have -1 bytes_read -- I did not guard it because I wanted to see "Success"  just to confirm

Comment: Check `errno` and/or `perror` right after `read` since it returns `-1` which indicates an error.

Comment: perror("read" returns "read: Invalid argument."  Now to spot the invalid arg.

Comment: I changed read_buffer and the BUF_SIZE to 720, which is the correct amount, but I still get invalid argument.  The problem must be events[i].data.fd.

Comment: Re "*I did not guard it because I wanted to see "Success" just to confirm*", `errno` (used by `perror`) is only guaranteed to be meaningful on error. Specifically, it's not guaranteed to be "Success" on success.

Comment: Re "*Now to spot the invalid arg*", On linux at least, the man page for `read` very precisely lists under what conditions EINVAL (and other errors) is returned.

Comment: Re "*it should be 720 bytes*", Note that `read` can always return less than requested. (This is not what's happening here, though.)

Comment: @ikegami - re your first comment "only guaranteed to be meaningful on error" -- can we assume that if there's no error reported then there was no error?  If it returns "Success" and not an error wouldn't that mean that there was no error?

Comment: Re "*an we assume that if there's no error reported then there was no error?*", Yes, if `read` returns `>=0`, no error occurred. /// Re "*If it returns "Success" and not an error wouldn't that mean that there was no error?*", Yes, but the converse isn't true. It outputs something other than success, it doesn't mean there was an error.